# Assign "selected" to radio label with jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label, selected

I have a group of radio inputs with associated labels.  There is some CSS magic to pretty up the buttons, and this works fine.  I need to be able to change the selected attribute of the label.

```
<input type='radio' id='radio1' name='resolution' value='0' selected />
<input type='radio' id='radio2' name='resolution' value='1' />
<label for='radio1' class='cb-enable selected' ><span>Open</span></label>
<label for='radio2' class='cb-disable ' ><span>Closed</span></label>
```

How would I go about setting the label selector with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input:radio[name='resolution']").change(function(){
    $("label").removeClass("selected");
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").toggleClass("selected", this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QKL5t/

Comment: Thanks for the updates.  I was looking for removeClass and toggleClass.  This works:  `$('label[for=radio1]').removeClass(\"selected\");` and `$('label[for=radio2]').toggleClass(\"selected\", this.checked);`